# Minimalistic approach to building with C++

Tags: c++, windows

I have been developing PHP apps for several years with Notepad++ & recently made the decision to learn C++.

After downloading the free trial of Visual Express 2010, as well as  a few of the popular frameworks such as QT and OpenCV, I noticed a rather **enormous jump** in hard drive space consumption.

Long story short, it took over 250 MB of software to produce my first "Hello World", a program that is less than 1 MB in size;

and an additional 750MB to produce a webcam app smaller than 5 MB that does nothing.

**So my question is:**

Is there a community, software, or technique that enables one to produce and compile C++ appications without the bloat?

Particularly: explain the advantage of using VS2010 over the minimalistic approach- besides the intellisense.

**UPDATE:**

So, I learned a few things:

1. It doesn't matter how much space V Studio and its components take up....*it's 2013 for crying out loud*
2. NewEgg.com still has the best deals on hardware.
3. Use [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/) Got it working in 5 minutes, and it's great for those who've worked a lot with the Unix console. Plus, I can continue developing in Notepad++ with little worry about cruft and bloat buildup- barring the sometimes gargantuan C++ libraries out there.

Also: I'm gonna keep VStudio express. It's free, and makes life **marginally easier** to build programs specifically for Windows. I have also learned that MingW makes life **marginally easier** to compile programs for linux.

Any corrections appreciated.

Comment: A plain editor and a compiler.

Comment: well you just need an editor and a compiler, so there's no bloat there. then the more libraries you add, the more space you'll use on disk

Comment: Are there any compilers in particular you'd recommend from experience? There is a nice list here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/663/ although I have read that Dev C++ is outdated?

Comment: That's an IDE for gcc/g++, of which there are smaller stand-alone distributions.

Comment: Since you've already worked with Notepad++, I see no reason why you can't use it for C++ programming as well.

Comment: @celtschk That sounds like a phenomenal idea!

Comment: I don't see what the big deal is - it's 2013. What's the problem if you take up 1GB of your 1TB drive for programming in C++? Is it not worth a measley 0.1% of your disk space?

Comment: I would recommend this: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html -- It is [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/), plus a few other very useful libraries, chief among them being [boost](http://www.boost.org/).  It clocks in at 22.8 megabytes. The reason I recommended that distribution, even though it comes with extra stuff you didn't ask for, is because it is so braindead simple to install (and the extra stuff really is very useful).  If you must have it smaller, you can of course go to the [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) website, but that is more of a hassle, imo.

Comment: Newegg current lists a 3 TB drive for $139 US. By my figuring that means your 250 MB is literally about 1 penny worth of drive space (and 750 MB, roughly three cents worth). Even if it took up a whole nickel's worth, would that honestly be a major concern?

Comment: note: visual studio express 2012 is free (and I assume 2010), you just enter an email one time.

Comment: I agree about the  triviality of a couple GIGs of space- but this is after less than ONE WEEK of learning C++... and I haven't even scratched the surface! How many progress bars does one need to see to produce anything meaningful- as subjective as that sounds- to get something together: the same reason why I have avoided Zend libraries when working with PHP.

Comment: @DudeSolutions As many as the number of libraries you plan on using. Realistically, you won't continuing increasing in disk space at anywhere near that rate, as you won't likely be using multiple Integrated Development Environments, nor whole frameworks on the scale of Qt (depending on how you installed it, you also installed an IDE, QtCreator, and complete toolchain along with it, which can take >500 MB of disk space!). If a library is useful, *use it*! If not, then don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, this doesn't matter.  The 1 GB or so of software you downloaded either provides you enough value to keep it, or you should simply delete it.  If you want a 1 MB development environment, look for some old Borland compiler from two decades ago...then you'll realize what a miraculous world we live in, with our huge hard drives that free us from having to care about 1 GB of space, even if two thirds of it is somehow a "waste" (say because you don't use the graphical parts of Qt).

The cost of 1 GB of disk space on your computer is probably less than the value spent on this question in its first day by people dropping by to let you know it's OK to use 1 GB of disk space in 2013.

If you're still not convinced, do a web search for "demo scene."

Comment: I agree- don't misunderstand that I am trying to conserve space on my hard drive. I was just a little concerned that I had to download so much, and I haven't even BEGUN yet...

Comment: I guess it's time to begin then.  :)  Maybe someday there will be a more "streaming" solution to downloading development packages, like when we start to watch a video online before it has finished loading.  Oh the other hand, maybe faster network connections will make that unnecessary for all but the most far-flung developers (say, those with internet available only via satphone).

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of using VS is that you can't produce native windows apps as easily without it. When you use VS you get the benefits of easy access to the windows API and other tools that VS provides. In terms of the space it takes up on your computer as everyone else is saying it is pretty much negligible considering how cheap memory is nowadays.

Comment: Okay! Now I learned something!

Comment: @DudeSolutions: No you didn't. The claim in this answer is false.

Comment: Why is it false I just said that it is significantly easier to use the API and produce a native looking app, not impossible

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Do tell. Alternative solutions welcome.

Comment: @aaronman: You said "you can't really produce native windows apps without it".  That is what is false. And it is not hard at all to use the windows API with mingw.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Understood. MingW, perhaps?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley all I meant is that it is easier not impossible

Comment: Hey, I can't read your intentions.  Only your statements. Downvote retracted. Though I still must leave a comment that "easier" is subjective and not all would agree.  For example, people who are accustomed to working with GCC on the command line in unix-like environments would feel much more comfortable, and have and easier time, with mingw than with VS.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley fair enough this is all opinion, but the thing is if you read the OP the answer everyone is upvoting doesn't answer the question at all and just points out that 1GB is not a lot of space which I think everyone knows. My answers at least is more useful than the other one